# Parsing XML in android, but not the attributes

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse a really simple XML in my android app, for example:

```
<data> 
    <section id="123">bla</section> 
    <area>blabla</area> 
</data>
```

But in every example I find I see how to extract the data in the attribute (id being 123) when what I need to extract is the data displayed - "bla" and "blabla".
How do I do that using SAXParser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [tutorial](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example) respond to exactly what you want hope you gonna enjoy

See how The characters method in the parser handler takes care of extreacting an element's text value

Answer (score 0):

The `characters` method in the parser handler takes care of an element's text value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the [characters](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/HandlerBase.html#characters%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, writing parsers by hand is of course fun & error-prone, I'd however recommend using a framework - even a simple one like the built in `android.sax` package.

Using the `StartElementListener` (if you want the attributes at all that is) & `EndTextListener` (captures the body text of the element):

```
class Section implements StartElementListener, EndTextElementListener {
    String mValue;
    String mId;
    @Override
    public void end(String body) {
        mValue = body;
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Attributes attributes) {
        mId = attributes.getValue("", "id");
    }
}
```

Listeners of these types are attached to `Element`s derived from a `RootElement`, like so:

```
Section section = new Section();
RootElement data = new RootElement("data");
// Use "requireChild" if a "section" is required as a child of "data".
Element s = data.getChild("section");
s.setStartElementListener(section);
s.setEndTextElementListener(section);
try {
    Xml.parse(xml, data.getContentHandler());
} catch (SAXException e) {
}
```

Basically, this helps you build content handlers for SAX that cares about the hierarchy and keeps track of what element you are parsing easily. Short & nifty code also I guess.